# Access webproject folder from another dll

Tags: .net, web

I have 2 projects in my solution:

-**ClassLibrary1**
 *Class1.cs
-**MvcApplication1**
*Areas
*Content
*Controllers
*Images

how do i access a file in **Images** folder from **ClassLibrary1** ? It has to be a physical file with path, not embedded in Resources.resx, also, i *cannot* put it in **\bin**

Comment: Via the image's physical path? If the image isn't embedded into the MvcApplication assembly then using the images path seems like the only possibility.

Comment: thats the point, how do i get the image path? if i call GetExecutingAssembly I end up with a path in temporary asp.net folder

Comment: Have you tried using: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase instead of .Location() ?  Location returns where the Assembly is currently executing from which may or may not be its "real" location on disk.  .CodeBase should return you that "real" location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)